# HTML character entities stripped when building org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, character-entities

I have a Java XML utility class. The `buildDocument()` method accepts an XML string and returns `org.w3c.dom.Document`. The particular XML I'm passing to it is an xhtml 1.1 document.

The issue is if there are HTML named entities like,

```
<p>Preserve dagger &dagger;</p>
```

the output is,

```
<p>Preserve dagger </p>
```

It does preserve `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;`.

Here is the class creating `Document`.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public final class XMLUtils {

    private XMLUtils() {
    }

    public static Document buildDocument(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        domFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        domFactory.setFeature(
            "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
        domFactory.setFeature(
            "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        domFactory.setCoalescing(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        try {
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            System.out.println("XML OUT: \n" + writer.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        return doc;
    }
}
```

I think these are the relevant dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.5.1-6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas on how to preserve these entities? Thanks, /w

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095451/java-xml-processing-entity-problem

Comment: @Naren I read through that question and I'm not sure it applies to this situation. I have DTD validation turned off. Was hoping to pass through all entities. I've been looking into an Entity Resolver - just not sure how to implement it yet, or if it will solve this problem.

Comment: When I set an entity resolver the `resolveEntity(publicId, systemId)` method is never called. I'm trying to turn on dtd loading but having to fix other cascading exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to find a solution to this problem, apparently it is difficult to search the right keywords... since I found this one *before* finding the best answer, I thought it was worth linking it here, even if it is on StackOverflow anyway. There you go: [Keep numeric character entity characters such as `&#10; &#13;` when parsing XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127660/keep-numeric-character-entity-characters-such-as-10-13-when-parsing-xml)

It is not quite satisfactory, but at least it explains very well why there is no better solution.