# Java XML - Java changes me &apos; and &quot; to ' and " when I generate the XML File

Tags: java, xml

I'm adding a new register to XML File. This File has a speacial characters like `&apos; and &quot;`. And when I generate the XML File the transformerFactory changes me this to ' and ".

This is my code:

```
Document document = documentBuilder.parse("Input.xml");
//Here I add the nodes in document
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

StreamResult result = new StreamResult("Result.xml");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I tried add this lines in transfomer, but didn't work:

```
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

Example:

Input:

```
<Users>
  <User Name="Daniel"> 
      <Option Name="Salt">jJ=&apos;\Cl%MST&quot;U.ivm/FwI+TJC=IalOJg2z8\L}b;&lt;=OZ}qz`|_|[`y~)J,pEbWx_</Option>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Output: I added Tom with other option Salt and when I generate the XMl Java changes me this characters `&apos; and &quot;` from Daniel and others users:

```
<Users>
   <User Name="Daniel"> 
     <Option Name="Salt">jJ='\Cl%MST"U.ivm/FwI+TJC=IalOJg2z8\L}b;&lt;=OZ}qz`|_|[`y~)J,pEbWx_</Option>
   </User>
   <User Name="Tom"> 
     <Option Name="Salt">salt1234</Option>
   </User>
 </Users>
```

What I want:

```
<Users>
       <User Name="Daniel">
         //Here there are &apos and &quot and in output no 
         <Option Name="Salt">jJ=&apos;\Cl%MST&quot;U.ivm/FwI+TJC=IalOJg2z8\L}b;&lt;=OZ}qz`|_|[`y~)J,pEbWx_</Option>
       </User>
       <User Name="Tom"> 
         <Option Name="Salt">salt1234</Option>
       </User>
     </Users>
```

How can escape this special characters when I generete the new XML File?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the output to be? The exact same as the current input?

Comment: No, I have an xml file with <users><user></user></users> and when I add a new user the transformer change me this characters from other users. This options are in the user.

Comment: What do the `<user>` and `<users>` tag have to do with your question? I do not see anywhere that you mentioned these in your original post.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. I assume that the Input you describe here is the input file to your code. Is the Output the generated XML file? If not, show what the actual generated file is and what is different from what you want.

Comment: Sorry, <users><user><Option Name="Salt"></Option></user></users>

Comment: I still do not understand what you are saying. Please read the link I gave above and also [ask]. Then edit your question to clarify what you need.

Comment: see edits at Output

Comment: What do you want the output to be instead?

Comment: See edits please, and sorry for my bad explanations.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, but i'm looking for a other way to do this. I don't want to replace values form original file.

Comment: I think replacing values in the original file is your best bet, even if you don't want to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128866/407651

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that properly with `javax.xml`. You could try to use `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ASCII")`, but both `"` as `'` are already plain ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the literal `&apos;` in your output, then you just need to escape the `&`. The input should be `&amp;apos;`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The output is the same. &amp;apos; --> &amp;apos;